# Problems with user settings

Tags: users, user-management

i have 2 users, mine and my moms, but the thing is that, from my mothers account i can enter the files and apps for my account (mine is the principal one btw) i dont want my mother to acces my files, as i created her's so there could be an improve on organization and their files are in their acccount, and mines on my account, so theres no dissorder, and also my privacity is important even if she is my mom. so please, help me know how to separate my files from her's, so when she neters her account she does not find my files and when i enter my account i dont find her files

Comment: which files can you actually see of your mother's? can you access and look at the folders in her home directory (/home/moms user name)?All users should be able to see the directory tree from the root directory (/). if you can see each other's home directories, then there may be some permission issues, but i believe that default setup 'protects' home directories.

Comment: i mean, i have installed steam in my account, the othe one has it too

Comment: even if it has just been installed in mine only

Comment: everything i do on 1 account automatically is done in the other